# Textbox text property not updating when calling delegate sub VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, textbox, delegates

I'm developing an inventory application for our department. I'm currently working on posting receipts. Items can be received from supplier or returned from an employee. If the material is received from employee, then I show another form that shows employee list, then the user select the employee. When the employee is selected, then I declare a delegate and invoking a sub in the original receipt form to update a TextBox with employee id and name. ***The problem is that The TextBox is not updated with the string that I'm passing through the delegate.*** I debugged the application and found that values are received in the sub, but TextBox not updated

Here is my code
This code in the Employee Selection Form

```
Public Class frmReceiptEmployeeSelection
    ...

    Private Sub dgvEmployee_CellClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgvEmployee.CellClick
        If e.RowIndex >= 0 And e.ColumnIndex = dgvEmployee.Columns("employeeSelect").Index Then
            Dim employeeId As Integer = dgvEmployee.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("employeeId").Value
            Dim selectionText As String = dgvEmployee.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("employeeNewCode").Value
            selectionText += "," + dgvEmployee.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("employeeName").Value

            Dim employeeSelectionDel As New EmployeeSelectionDelegate(AddressOf frmAddReceipt.selectEmployeeForReceipt)
            employeeSelectionDel.Invoke(employeeId, selectionText)
            Me.Close()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

and Here is the code in the Receipt Form:

```
Public Delegate Sub EmployeeSelectionDelegate(ByVal x As Integer, ByVal s As String)

Public Class frmAddReceipt
    ...

    Public Sub selectEmployeeForReceipt(ByVal employeeId As Integer, ByVal selectionText As String)
        selectedEmployeeId = employeeId
        txtReceiptEmployeeSelection.Text = selectionText
    End Sub
End Class
```

I spent too much time looking for a solution for updating TextBox with the passed string through the delegate, but without success.

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using a delegate at all here? Why not just call the method directly?

Comment: Hi Jon, I tried what you suggessted. I called the sub directly frmAddReceipt.selectEmployeeReceipt(employeeId,selectionText). The values are passed correctly, but the textbox is not updated visually. The textbox keeps empty although its text property is updated. This is really strange issue.

Comment: Well I suspect the problem is in code we can't see - maybe you're creating multiple instances of `frmAddReceipt`, or maybe the `txtReceiptEmployeeSelection` textbox isn't the one you think it is...

Comment: here is my code for create intance of frmAddReceipt

`For Each child In Me.OwnedForms  
            If TypeOf child Is frmReceiptEmployeeSelection Then  <br/>
                child.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal  <br/>
                child.Focus()  <br/>
                Exit Sub  <br/>
            End If  <br/>
        Next  <br/>

        Dim selectReceiptEmployeeForm As New  <br/> frmReceiptEmployeeSelection()  <br/>
        selectReceiptEmployeeForm.Show(Me)`  <br/>

believe me, `txtReceiptEmployeeSelection` is the target textbox

Comment: Please don't add code into comments like that. Ideally, try to reproduce the issue in a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: here is my code for create intance of frmAddReceipt
  
`For Each child In Me.OwnedForms  
            If TypeOf child Is frmReceiptEmployeeSelection Then  
                child.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal  
                child.Focus()  
                Exit Sub  
            End If  
        Next  

        Dim selectReceiptEmployeeForm As New  frmReceiptEmployeeSelection()  
        selectReceiptEmployeeForm.Show(Me)`  
  
believe me, `txtReceiptEmployeeSelection` is the target textbox

@jon-skeet

Comment: sorry for inconvience